# Excel VBA IF statement for Msgbox (range1<>range2+range3) then

Tags: excel, vba, compare, msgbox

VBA noob here,

So i have 3 Columns (A,B and C)

```
A = Received Goods
B = Sent Goods for Shop 1
C = Sent Goods for Shop 2
```

I want values cells in  **B**+**C** = **A**  otherwise give me an error message.

Here is my code:

```
If Range("A1").End(xlDown).Value <> Range("B1").End(xlDown).Value & Range("C1").End(xlDown).Value Then
MsgBox "Error, wrong number of sent goods"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is it:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Warning()

    Dim A As Long, B As Long, C As Long 'in case you have floating numbers use Single or Double instead

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NameOfYourSheet")
        A = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
        B = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
        C = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)
    End With

    If B + C <> A Then
        MsgBox "Error, wrong number of sent goods"
    End If

End Sub
```

I'm assuming you are trying the last row of every column.